# Error when calling methods within a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I've defined a javascript class for matrix transformations (of points to be drawn on an html5 canvas) which has multiple methods (e.g. multiply,rotate, scale, translate). In my rotate method, I need to call multiply, but since it is another method defined within the class, it has to be called in a way different from if was called outside of the class definition. For the class constructor, I have:

```
function Transform() {
            this.identity();
        }
```

and for the rotate method:

```
Transform.prototype.rotateX = function(rad) {
            var c = Math.cos(rad);
            var s = Math.sin(rad);
            var rx = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, c, -s, 0],
                      [0, s, c, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 1]];
            this.m = multiply(rx, this.m);
            document.write('matrix rx:<br />');
            display(rx);
            document.write('rx * this.m =<br />');
            display(this.m);
        };
```

I'm coming from a C++ background with OOP, so this way of defining classes seems a little strange, but it seems that you should be able to call a function defined in the class without using the dot operator similar to how in C++ if you have a method defined using the scope qualification operator, you can freely access any of the class' data. For some reason, in javascript, this must not be the case, as I'm getting the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: multiply is not defined`

What is the proper way to call methods defined in a Javascript class both inside and outside of the class definition?

Comment: where is `multiply` defined.... you might have to use `this.multiply` if it is added to the prototype

Comment: Do not use document.write, use [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console).

Answer (score 1):

> but it seems that you should be able to call a function defined in the class without using the dot operator similar to how in C++

Nope. In JavaScript, the `this` is not optional, so if `multiply` is attached to the object (from the prototype, or just assigned to it in the constructor), you need `this`:

```
this.m = this.multiply(rx, this.m);
```

You might be thinking of calling an in-scope function, which *doesn't* require `this`. Here's an example of all three:

```js
function Thingy(prop) {
  this.prop = prop;

  // Here's a "method" we add in the constructor:
  this.method1 = function() {
    snippet.log("Thingy#method1, prop = " + this.prop);
  };
};
Thingy.prototype.method2 = function() {
  snippet.log("Thingy#method2, prop = " + this.prop);
};
Thingy.prototype.method3 = function() {
  snippet.log("Thingy#method3, prop = " + this.prop);

  this.method1();
  this.method2();
  inScopeOnlyForMethod3();
  inScopeOnlyForMethod3.call(this);

  function inScopeOnlyForMethod3() {
    snippet.log("inScopeOnlyForMethod3, prop = " + this.prop);
  }
};

var t = new Thingy(42);
t.method3();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that `this` in JavaScript is *fundamentally different* from `this` in C++. In JavaScript, `this` for `function` functions is usually determined by *how the function was called*, not where it's defined. (ES2015 — the latest JavaScript standard — defines "arrow" functions that don't use the `function` keyword, which inherit `this` from the context where they're created.)

Similarly, C++ classes are *fundamentally different* from JavaScript's constructor functions and prototypes. (And note that you can do JavaScript's prototypicaly inheritance with constructor functions, or directly via `Object.create`.)